# pg_wal directory is full in postgres db

Tags: postgresql

I have postgres 10 where pg_wal is getting full. I have files pg_wal directory from Dec'2020. I have enabled "archive" but I was getting archiver error and my application stopped working. Since this issue is on Production, I have disabled the archive.

Is it safe to remove old files from pg_wal which is dated on Dec'2020 and Jan'2021?

I can see this:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots;

 slot_name | plugin | slot_type | datoid | database | temporary | active | active_pid | xmin | catalog_xmin | restart_lsn  | c onfirmed_flush_lsn
-----------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+--------------+---------------------
  m9t0179g |        |  physical |        |          |         f |      f |            |      |              |   50/B780000 |
       m9t |        |  physical |        |          |         f |      f |            |      |              | 3B0/EB000920 |
```

Comment: What do you mean by disabling the archive?

Comment: As per the replication_slots output, Is it safe to remove them?

Answer (score 2):

No. Never manually remove files.

If you set `archive_mode` to `off` (and restart) or change `archive_command` to something like `/bin/true` (and reload), then PostgreSQL will start deleting old WAL segments all by itself. Just give it a little time.

If that alone doesn't do the trick, there must be something else that blocks removing WAL segments, like a stale replication slot. In your case, the two stale inactive replication slots are the problem. Get rid of them with

```
SELECT pg_drop_replication_slot('m9t0179g');
SELECT pg_drop_replication_slot('m9t');
```

Both slots are suspicious because they are not `active`, that is, currently not in use. At least the first one is certainly stale, since it is 3.5 TB behind the second one.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Once I delete these replication slots, do I need to restart the services? Will the old files in pg_wal directory be automatically cleaned as per value defined in "wal_keep_segments"?

Comment: It will be cleaned automatically.

Comment: How did you recognize that the replication slots are "stale"?

Comment: @Marc I have added an explanation.